# Connect to AJAX file. Joomla

Tags: ajax, plugins, joomla, connect

I can't to connect to ajax conf.php file because of (_JEXEC) then i use jquery code:

```
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "conf.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#flash").fadeOut("slow");
$("#content").html(html);
} 
});
});
```

How can I connect in other working way to that file ?

Comment: trying using `define('_JEXEC', 1);`

Comment: oh man!!! thank you so much. You can't imagine how much you helped me. thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: Glad it works. Please mark the answer below as "correct" by clicking the tick icon to the left of the answer so other knows it has been solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );` usually restricts ajax

functions therefore you will need to use `define('_JEXEC', 1);`

Notice that you need to use `define`, not `defined`

Comment: I have a new problem here, it's really strange - When I use some of joomla methods for example JRequest:getDbo etc. the conf.php files refuses to work. But if I use simple insert to mysql code, it works fine.  What is wrong with it ?

Comment: @Jonuux - please ask a new question regarding this problem with a bit more detail. thanks.